# Use SQL in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So, this might be somewhat of a stupid question, but I couldn't find enough material about it or I just don't get it.

What I am trying to do is, use SQL-statements in my VBA-code.
I know one can use: DoCmd.runSQL, but this just doesn't seem to work for me, it always spits out error messages.

For Example, I try:

```
Set StringArray() = DoCmd.RunSQL("Select column from table")
```

or

```
If (DoCmd.RunSQL(Select sum(column) from table where coulmn = '" + Me.txtField + '") > 0) Then
```

but it always throws something like: Compiling error. Function or variable expected.

I don't know if I just understood something wrong, but I thought you can use normal SQL-Statements with DoCmd.runSQL.

Comment: I think you need a pointer to what to search for in the documentation, rather than explicit answers. Look for CurrentDb.OpenRecordset and CurrentDb.Execute

Comment: Here is some introduction: http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/472-using-docmd-runsql-return-values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *GetRows* using this skeleton:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.Openrecordset("Select column from table") 

StringArray = rs.GetRows()    
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
```

Look up the documentation for GetRows for the full story.

Comment: I'd also like to address Sam, Andre and Vitayata which gave me useful hints.

Answer (score 2):

DoCmd.RunSQL is a method. It does not return result, it carries out some action. Thus, you cannot assign it to StringArray().

See more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-runsql-method-access